# How to make RewriteRule work only if URL contains specific string?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to add `RewriteRule` which works only if there is a certain string in the URL, otherwise I need to load the content from another folder. If the URL contains the string `test`, I need to send it to `index.php` as a parameter, else the content should be loaded from the `directory` folder.

For example: The root folder of the project is `new_project`. If the URL is `http://localhost/new_project/test/something/`, then I need to send `test/something/` to `index.php` as parameter. Else if the URL is something like `http://localhost/new_project/something/`, then I need to load the content from `directory/something` folder.

Following is the `.htaccess` file I've written so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# Serve other requests from the directory/ folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ directory/$1 [L]
```

What needs to be changed in the above `.htaccess` file so that the occurrence of `test` string in the URL passes the string after the string `test` along with the string `test` to `index.php` and if the URL doesn't contain the string `test` then loads the content from the `directory` folder?

Comment: Where are you putting `test` in the url? Show some samples.

Comment: I have added some sample URLs and scenarios in the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the `test/` inside the `RewriteRule` itself. Place the more specific rewrite rule before the "catch-all" `directory/` rewrite rule.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# All requests starting with `test/` go to index (without the `test` part).
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] # Not sure how GET parameters starting with `?/` behave.

# All others go to directory. Assuming not a valid file or dir.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ directory/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Actually I need to send the requests not containing the string `test` to `directory`. If the URL contains `test` string, then only it needs to passed to `index.php`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The second htaccess did exactly what I wanted. But using the first `.htaccess` file caused a `500` error and following error was in the Apache error log:

`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`